# WIX And NAnt : Unable to build WIX source code

Tags: wix, nant, wix3.6

I am trying my hands on source code of [WIX 3.6](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.6.2026.0/) to debug something as well as learn something.

On executing `make.bat` (present in root folder of WIX source) file, first i got NAnt not found. So I downloaded [NAnt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nant/) and updated make.bat file. On executing the file again I am getting this error

```
NAnt 0.91 (Build 0.91.3881.0; alpha2; 8/17/2010)
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///D:/wix36-sources/wix.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
Target(s) specified: inc

[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VSIP\10.0\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VSIP\10.0\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
 [property] Target framework changed to "Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0".
 [property] Read-only property "dir.hhw" cannot be overwritten.
 [property] Read-only property "hhw-found" cannot be overwritten.

BUILD FAILED - 2 non-fatal error(s), 2 warning(s)

D:\wix36-sources\wix.build(65,4):
Build file 'D:\wix36-sources\test\wixtests.build' does not exist.
```

I have .Net framework 4.0 installed on my local. Also I searched through registry for the registry key mentioned in the error and didn't found. Am I using right version of NAnt?

Comment: You say you've updated the make.bat. What have you changed?

Comment: I updated NAnt path in make.bat file.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have all of the prerequisites [as described in the documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/building_wix.htm)?

> In order to fully build WiX, you must have the following Frameworks and SDKs installed:
>
> - NAnt (0.90 or later)
> - The following components from the Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, Visual Studio 2008, Microsoft Windows 7 SDK, and/or Visual Studio 2010:
>
>   - x86 and x64 compilers, headers and libraries
>   - IA64 headers and libraries are optional, but they are necessary for IA64 custom action support
>   - If you want to be able to build optimized IA64 binaries, you'll need both the Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5 SDK AND Visual Studio 2008 installed; or the Microsoft Windows 7 SDK AND Visual Studio 2010.
>   - HTML Help SDK 1.4 or higher [installed to Program Files or Program Files (x86)]

The missing registry key seems to be related to the VisualStudio SDK - you don't need this for basic WiX.

If you have all of the prerequisites, try passing the `-debug` switch to Nant for more detailed debugging output.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem:

> [readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VSIP\10.0\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
>
> [readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VSIP\10.0\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';

If you used Visual Studio 2010 SP1 you need [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21835)

Comment: If you are using VS2008 - try: **Visual Studio 2008 SDK 1.1** @ http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=508